# celery task scheduled but not executed at ETA

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have my celery configured as following:

```
# create context tasks in celery
celery = Celery(
    __name__,
    # redis
    backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
    broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
    include=['app.celery_tasks.tasks']
)
celery.conf.timezone = 'US/Pacific'
celery.conf.broker_transport_options = {'visibility_timeout': 3600*24}
celery.conf.task_routes = {
    'tasks.periodic': {
        'queue': 'periodic',
        'routing_key': 'tasks.periodic'
    },
    'tasks.generate_report': {
        'queue': 'report',
        'routing_key': 'tasks.generate_report'
    }
}
```

Then I'm using this helper method to get eta for all my report tasks

```
def get_eta_time(time_d=8):
    tz = timezone('US/Pacific')
    ct = datetime.now(tz=tz)
    eta = ct + timedelta(hours=time_d)
    return eta
```

The thing I'm encountering is I can see the tasks are scheduled using the celery control but they are not executed when the eta arrives. However, when I tried to restart my celery workers, these tasks got picked up immediately. Is there anything I missed in my celery config?

My tasks are triggered as following:

```
eta = get_eta_time()
generate_report.apply_async(args=(log_location, repetition_count+1), queue='report', eta=eta)
```

My periodical queue works as expected, but my report queue is not making any sense to me.

Comment: What version of celery are you using?  There are some issues with using a non-UTC timezone in older versions of celery.

Comment: yeah, I looked at those posts too, but I'm using 4.2.1 the latest. It's like the workers only fetch tasks when they first started, but no more fetching after the first time. And the weirdest part is it was working fine 2 weeks ago, and I didn't make any significant changes after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be some hardware issue. I switch to a different machine and it is working now.

Comment: how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).